# What is industrial statistics?

Tags: self-study, references, terminology, definition, application

We have a course titled "Industrial Statistics". But I don't understand what is industrial statistics?

What I have understood after searching some sites is only that

> Industrial statistics measure a variety of different characteristics about the mining, manufacturing and energy producing sectors.

Can you please explain?

Comment: I wouldn't agonise over the definition. Any interpretation as statistical methods that are or could be used with industrial data might fit the term, but expect a large range of interpretations, from a standard mix of techniques with industrial examples to a mix of techniques with deliberate orientation to industrial needs: but that mix could still vary considerably. There might be lots on experimental design, lots on quality control, lots on sales forecasting, etc.

Comment: And the definition you found concerns statistics - i.e. data - about industry, rather than statistics as applied in industry.

Comment: There is a tag [tag:engineering-statistics] Have a look, and consider adding it to your post!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nick Cox, but if you'd like a definition this seems like a useful one:

> Industrial Statistics is concerned with maintaining and improving the
> quality of goods and services. It involves a broad range of
> statistical tools but maintaining and improving quality involves an
> overall approach to the management of industrial processes that
> transcends the use of these specific tools. Variability is inherent in
> all processes, whether they be manufacturing processes or service
> processes. This variability must be controlled to create high quality
> goods and services and must be reduced to improve quality. Industrial
> Statistics focuses on the use of statistical thinking, i.e., the
> appreciation of the inherent variability of all processes. It also
> focuses on developing skills for modeling data and designing
> experiments that can lead to improvements in performance and
> reductions in variablity [sic].

$-$ https://math.unm.edu/undergraduate/statistics/industrial-statistics

If you want something pithier, there's this:

> ..."industrial statistics” refers to the use of statistics to promote
> the development, testing, production, and marketing of goods and the
> processes that support these efforts.

$-$ David M. Steinberg (2016) Industrial statistics: The challenges and the
research, Quality Engineering, 28(1), 45-59. https://doi.org/10.1080/08982112.2015.1100453